# Determine stable version of dependencies

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, nuspec

I have a pre-release package, after installing it in other projects, some unstable packages installs e.g. EntityFramework

Alternatively, I set fix version of EF in nuspec file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="Effort.EF6" version="1.3.0" />
</dependencies>
```

Is it possible to determine only install stable version of some dependencies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the exact version that you want to reference in the dependency using the syntax outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards) -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="Effort.EF6" version="[1.3.0]" />
</dependencies>
```